# How do I lock the layout of my android program to one orientation

Tags: java, android, orientation, sensors, screen-orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t want activity to be destroyed/created when phone is rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663427/dont-want-activity-to-be-destroyed-created-when-phone-is-rotated)

I'm trying to write a program that needs smooth orientation sensor samples as the phone is rotated all around. Every time the orientation of the phone is changed, it interrupts the data and freezes the program while the layout changes. How can I lock it in one orientation (landscape or portrait, it doesn't matter)?

I assume it has something to do with `android:layout` in the xml file, but I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663427/dont-want-activity-to-be-destroyed-created-when-phone-is-rotated) looks promising to me (used `[android] [screen-orientation]` in the SO search box)

Answer (score 12):

Simplest and one of ways to do this would be having `android:screenOrientation="portrait|landscape"`
property for the `<activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 4):

In java code it will look like this:

```
super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax in the manifest file for a particular activity:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

The above never seems to work for me.

I always use:-

**setRequestedOrientation(0);**

Changing the value at the end will give horizintal/vertical lock.
Make sure to catch the keyboard being opened in the manifest though, if in portrait mode, as it may give unexpected results.

Comment: My IDE won't let me use a number, says it must be one of the constants from the docs. Is there an alternative?