# Android, locking screen and handling rotation

Tags: android, multithreading, state

I am making a very simple game (in the hope of learning a bit mor of Android programming as well as doing something functional) and will be locking the screen so its always in landscape mode to play the game.

I have around 5 background threads running (timers, game playing time, level time etc) via asyncTask.

According to my book i still have to have something like `task=(RotationAwareTask)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();`

and

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() { 
    task.detach(); 

    return(task); 
  }
```

to save the state in case for example a phone call comes in...
and a child static class (RotationAwareTask)

This is pretty confusing in the book, is there a simple example that any of you guys are aware of (link to some site)? Or some set of "standard" code that you guys keep reusing that is easier to understand? Just as an example...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is set android:screenOrientation attribute in your  manifest element instead.

[How is application orientation (landscape or portrait) locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663427/dont-want-activity-to-be-destroyed-created-when-phone-is-rotated)

Comment: ok... then I wont have to bother about the activity being recreated if a call comes in or the user pauses etc?

Comment: You should only do this if you are *sure* this is the right thing to do. It often is for games, but often not for more general applications that want their resources reloaded to match the new configuration. For these apps, using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is the right thing to do.

Comment: Good advice, but he did say it was a game.