# How can i stop orientation change in android table?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

Hi i am developing android application in tablet version. Here i am facing problem with orientation so i want to make my application in portrait mode only. For that i Used attribute like below snippet for each and every activity in my application.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Application is running perfectly while testing in portrait mode. But it is not good while testing application with tablet physical position with landscape. It is first going to landscape then immediately going to portrait.

I used programmatically making the activity in portrait but no effect. Please provide me any help.
Here is my programmatic orientation fix

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

I tested in Motorolo device

Please suggest me to avoid my application going to landscape.

Comment: [CommonsWare-Guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2663607/1479570) to the rescue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the reason why orientation changes are occurring in android tablet. In ICS (version 4.0+) the tablet have the option like "Don't  keep activities" in settings>> Developer tools>>

If the user checked that option the paused activity will killed and created when it is call again. what i mean the activity won't go for onPause() state it will go for onDestroy() and it will created again when press on back key. So the orientation behavior is different.
I did not get the idea how to handle it from our android code

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="abc.xyz.dd.MainScreen" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

By adding this in manifest file it will prevent from changing to landscape mode.

Comment: Hi i used this one only. while performing finish activity first going to landscape mode the after going to portrait in my motorolo tablet

Comment: First, don't use setRequestedOrientation() if you can avoid it. Use the android:screenOrientation attribute in your <activity> manifest element instead.

Comment: Used that also but no effect.

Comment: activity will be in portrait but before that it is going to landscape for few millisecond and come back to portrait. I am using motorolo tablet and auto rotate is checked in my device.

Comment: do this run ur proj in protrait mode and then filp to landscape then check what happens...AFAIK it will not happen like that...

Comment: Yes while running in portrait mode there is no issue